# Markup is broken migrating from CKEditor 4 to CKEditor 5

Tags: ckeditor, wysiwyg, ckeditor5, ckeditor4.x

In CKeditor 4 my content looks like this:

[image]

I tried to migrate to CKEditor 5, made a custom build with full page HTML support, styles support, etc. I copied full HTML which was used in CKEditor 4 and tried it in CKEditor 5 and got this:

[image]

It's nowhere near I expected.

Tried full page HTML demo from documentation - and it is still the same broken markup:

[image]

Does anyone know if anything obvious is missing here?

HTML:

```
<p><span style="color: transparent; display: none; height: 0; max-height: 0; max-width: 0; opacity: 0; overflow: hidden; mso-hide: all; visibility: hidden; width: 0;">Your return</span></p>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="pc-email-body" role="presentation" style="table-layout: fixed;" width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" class="pc-email-body-inner" valign="top"><!--[if gte mso 9]>
            <v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t">
                <v:fill type="tile" src="" color="#f4f4f4"/>
            </v:background>
            <![endif]--><!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]><table width="620" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation"><tr><td width="620" align="center" valign="top"><![endif]-->
            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="pc-email-container" role="presentation" style="margin: 0 auto; max-width: 620px;" width="100%">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" style="padding: 0 10px;" valign="top">
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="20" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <!-- BEGIN MODULE: E-Commerce 6 -->

                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td bgcolor="#ffffff" class="pc-sm-p-30-10-20 pc-xs-p-15-0-25" style="padding: 30px 20px 20px; background-color: #ffffff; border-radius: 8px; box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);" valign="top">
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding: 0 20px; font-size: 0;" valign="top"><!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation"><tr><td width="75" valign="top"><![endif]-->
                                                <div class="pc-sm-mw-100pc" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; max-width: 75px; height: 1px; vertical-align: top; line-height: 1px; font-size: 1px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]></td><td width="370" valign="top"><![endif]-->

                                                <div class="pc-sm-mw-100pc" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; max-width: 370px; vertical-align: top;">
                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td align="center" class="pc-fb-font" style="padding: 10px 0; font-family: 'Fira Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 24px; font-weight: 700; line-height: 34px; letter-spacing: -0.4px; color: #151515;" valign="top">New Arrivals.</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                                </div>
                                                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]></td><td width="75" valign="top"><![endif]-->

                                                <div class="pc-sm-mw-100pc" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; max-width: 75px; vertical-align: top;">
                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td align="center" style="padding: 13px 0 10px;" valign="top">
                                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border-collapse: separate;">
                                                                <tbody>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td align="center" style="border-radius: 14px; border: 1px solid #CDCED2; padding: 6px 9px;" valign="top">
                                                                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">
                                                                            <tbody>
                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                    <td valign="middle"><a class="pc-fb-font" href="http://example.com" style="text-decoration: none; font-family: 'Fira Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; display: block; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 500; color: #4B4B4B; line-height: 14px; white-space: nowrap;"><span>See all</span></a></td>
                                                                                    <td style="padding-left: 3px;" valign="middle"><img alt="" height="9" src="https://www.clicksit.com/upsell/images/arrow-right-gray.png" style="display: block; border: 0; text-decoration: none; line-height: 100%; outline: 0; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic" width="6" /></td>
                                                                                </tr>
                                                                            </tbody>
                                                                        </table>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </tbody>
                                                            </table>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                                </div>
                                                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]--></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center" style="font-size: 0;" valign="top"><!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation"><tr><td width="50%" valign="top"><![endif]-->
                                                <div class="pc-sm-mw-50pc pc-xs-mw-100pc" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; max-width: 280px; vertical-align: top; text-align: left;">
                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td style="padding: 20px;" valign="top">
                                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                                                                <tbody>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td align="center" valign="top"><img alt="" src="https://www.clicksit.com/upsell/images/ecommerce-6-image-1.jpg" style="border: 0; line-height: 100%; outline: 0; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; display: block; max-width: 100%; height: auto; color: #151515; Margin: 0 auto;" /></td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td height="16" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </tbody>
                                                                <tbody>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td align="center" class="pc-fb-font" style="font-family: 'Fira Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 700; line-height: 34px; letter-spacing: -0.3px; color: #151515;" valign="top">Cable-Knit Merino Wool</td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td height="4" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </tbody>
                                                                <tbody>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td align="center" class="pc-fb-font" style="font-family: 'Fira Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 500; color: #9B9B9B;" valign="top">&pound;233</td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td height="17" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </tbody>
                                                                <tbody>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td align="center" valign="top">
                                                                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">
                                                                            <tbody>
                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                    <td align="center" bgcolor="#1595E7" style="padding: 13px 17px; border-radius: 8px; background-color: #1595E7;" valign="top"><a class="pc-fb-font" href="http://example.com" style="line-height: 24px; text-decoration: none; word-break: break-word; font-weight: 500; display: block; font-family: 'Fira Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: #ffffff;">Shop now</a></td>
                                                                                </tr>
                                                                            </tbody>
                                                                        </table>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </tbody>
                                                            </table>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                                </div>
                                                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]></td><td width="50%" valign="top"><![endif]-->

                                                <div class="pc-sm-mw-50pc pc-xs-mw-100pc" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; max-width: 280px; vertical-align: top;">
                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td style="padding: 20px;" valign="top">
                                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                                                                <tbody>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td align="center" valign="top"><img alt="" src="https://www.clicksit.com/upsell/images/ecommerce-6-image-2.jpg" style="border: 0; line-height: 100%; outline: 0; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; display: block; max-width: 100%; height: auto; color: #151515; Margin: 0 auto;" /></td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td height="16" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </tbody>
                                                                <tbody>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td align="center" class="pc-fb-font" style="font-family: 'Fira Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 700; line-height: 34px; letter-spacing: -0.3px; color: #151515;" valign="top">Runway Striped Cotton</td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td height="4" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </tbody>
                                                                <tbody>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td align="center" class="pc-fb-font" style="font-family: 'Fira Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 500; color: #9B9B9B;" valign="top">&pound;246</td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td height="17" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </tbody>
                                                                <tbody>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td align="center" valign="top">
                                                                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">
                                                                            <tbody>
                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                    <td align="center" bgcolor="#1595E7" style="padding: 13px 17px; border-radius: 8px; background-color: #1595E7;" valign="top"><a class="pc-fb-font" href="http://example.com" style="line-height: 24px; text-decoration: none; word-break: break-word; font-weight: 500; display: block; font-family: 'Fira Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: #ffffff;">Shop now</a></td>
                                                                                </tr>
                                                                            </tbody>
                                                                        </table>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </tbody>
                                                            </table>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                                </div>
                                                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]--></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center" style="font-size: 0;" valign="top"><!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation"><tr><td width="50%" valign="top"><![endif]-->
                                                <div class="pc-sm-mw-50pc pc-xs-mw-100pc" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; max-width: 280px; vertical-align: top;">​</div>
                                                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]></td><td width="50%" valign="top"><![endif]-->

                                                <div class="pc-sm-mw-50pc pc-xs-mw-100pc" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; max-width: 280px; vertical-align: top;">&nbsp;</div>
                                                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]--></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <!-- END MODULE: E-Commerce 6 -->

                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="20" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]--></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The HTML behind your question?

Comment: @ScottHunter added sample to the question